# not able to change page by clicking button React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to change the page when I click on the button. From the following code, all I am getting is a blank page when I click on that button.

home.js

```
import React from "react";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
function Home() {
    const history = useHistory();

    const routeChange = () => {
        let path = `./sponsorSignUp`;
        history.push(path);
    }

    return (
           <button className="btn btn-light font-weight-bold" onClick={routeChange}>Sign Up</button>)
export default Home;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Pages/home";
import sponsorSignUp from "./Pages/sponsorSignUp";

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <section className="container">
                <Link exact to="/"/>
            </section>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="./sponsorSignUp" component={sponsorSignUp}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Structure
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhKjo.png)

Comment: What version of react-router/react-router-dom are you using? Version 6?

Comment: how to check this

Comment: What do you have specified in your package.json file? The reason I ask is that v6 allows for using relative paths, pre-v6 do not. v6 doesn't have `Switch` components though, it was replaced by a `Routes` component.

Comment: react-router-dom:5.2.0         react-router:3

Comment: Ok, well, for starters you should be on the same version for both react-router and react-router-dom. And secondly, relative paths don't work in v5.

Comment: pls, can you make changes in my code for this. and I updated the router version

Comment: You could probably just remove the "." from the paths, i.e. `path="/sponsorSignUp"` versus `path="./sponsorSignUp"` and `history.push("/sponsorSignUp")` versus `history.push("./sponsorSignUp")`.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked. Finally, I am able to change the page. :)

Comment: Great. Voting to close as "unreproducible, caused by typo". Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

In this scenario react can't supported it, so that's why you can use this code. It's a react bug and you can easily resolved it by using it. `setTimeout(() => {  window.location.reload()  }, 1000);`